# TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big dataframe and I try to split that and after `concat` that.
I use

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('et_users.csv', header=None, names=names2, chunksize=100000)
for chunk in df2:
    chunk['ID'] = chunk.ID.map(rep.set_index('member_id')['panel_mm_id'])

df2 = pd.concat(chunk, ignore_index=True)
```

But it return an error

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Well error is clear but even if you did pass a list of dataframes you're overwriting the ID column in your loop: `for chunk in df2:
    chunk['ID'] = chunk.ID.map(rep.set_index('member_id')['panel_mm_id'])` what is your intention here? Are you trying to create some new df? what you should do is append each chunk to some list and then call `concat` on it

Comment: @EdChum I try to replace values in `chunk['ID]` from other df. and next I should use `chunk = chunk.dropna()` and then I should concatenate chunks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IIUC you want the following:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('et_users.csv', header=None, names=names2, chunksize=100000)
chunks=[]
for chunk in df2:
    chunk['ID'] = chunk.ID.map(rep.set_index('member_id')['panel_mm_id'])
    chunks.append(chunk)

df2 = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```

You need to append each chunk to a list and then use `concat` to concatenate them all, also I think the `ignore_index` may not be necessary but I may be wrong

Comment: I needed only in list? thats all? I think the problem was another. thank you!) But after that I got another problem: `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory`. chunksize didn't help. Is any way to fix that problem?

Comment: sure!) But after that I got another problem: pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory. chunksize didn't help. Is any way to fix that problem?

Comment: Where does this error occur, in the last part when concatenating? If so what you may need to do is write out and append each chunk e.g. `for chunk in df2:
    chunk.ID.map(rep.set_index('member_id')['panel_mm_id']).to_csv(output_dir, modex='a')`

Comment: It's not any way to concat that?

Comment: @nikhilvj the memory error you refer to was never going to be resolved by reading in the csv either whole or in chunks so your comment is irrelevant, the memory required to read in a large csv doesn't get resolved by doing this. Besides the OP never included that problem in their question, it was a follow up comment

Answer (score 186):

I was getting the same issue, and just realised that we have to pass the (multiple!) dataframes as a LIST in the first argument instead of as multiple arguments!

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
b = pd.DataFrame()
c = pd.concat(a,b) # errors out:
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

c = pd.concat([a,b]) # works.
```

If the processing action doesn't require ALL the data to be present, then is no reason to keep saving all the chunks to an external array and process everything only after the chunking loop is over: that defeats the whole purpose of chunking. We use chunksize because we want to do the processing ***at each chunk*** and free up the memory for the next chunk.

In terms of OP's code, they need to create another empty dataframe and concat the chunks into there.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame() # create empty df for collecting chunks
df2 = pd.read_csv('et_users.csv', header=None, names=names2, chunksize=100000)
for chunk in df2:
    chunk['ID'] = chunk.ID.map(rep.set_index('member_id')['panel_mm_id'])
    df3 = pd.concat([df3,chunk], ignore_index=True)

print(df3)
```

However, I'd like to reiterate that chunking was invented precisely to ***avoid*** building up all the rows of the entire CSV into a single DataFrame, as that is what causes out-of-memory errors when dealing with large CSVs. We don't want to just shift the error down the road from the `pd.read_csv()` line to the `pd.concat()` line. We need to craft ways to finish off the bulk of our data processing ***inside*** the chunking loop. In my own use case I'm eliminating away most of the rows using a df query and concatenating only the fewer required rows, so the final df is much smaller than the original csv.

Answer (score 10):

Last line must be in following format:

```
df2=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,...], ignore_index=True)
```

The thing is dataframes to be concatenated need to be passed as list/tuple.

Answer (score 6):

Like what they said, you need to pass it in as a list. Also, it may help to make sure it's in a DataFrame prior to using concat.

i.e.

```
chunks = pd.DataFrame(chunks)
df2 = pd.concat([chunks], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
finalexcelsheet = pd.DataFrame()

for file in filenames:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='DL PRB')
    finalexcelsheet = finalexcelsheet.append(
        df, ignore_index=True)

# finalexcelsheet dataframe contain all files data.
```