# Use loop to concatenate subset files in separate files from separate links

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched for some other questions which may relate to the solution to mine,
but have no luck.
In short, I have 29 separate files in the same working directory,
and I want to concatenate them.
But I encountered the error like below:

```
File b'C:\\....\\filename_1206_29.csv' does not exist:
```

I know it is because the pandas read_csv(r"link") which needs a "r" there.
I tried adding pd.read_csv("", "r") but not work.

My code is as below:

```
link=r"C:\....\{}" # I marked part of the link

for i in range(0,29):
    i+=1
    if len(str(int(i)))==1:
        i='0'+str(int(i)) # if i is one digit add a 0 in front
    else:
        i=str(int(i))
    filename="Scopus_FrOid_1206_{}.csv" # 29 files from 01.csv to 29.csv
    search=filename.format(i)
    searchstring=link.format(search) # all the links of the files
    pre=r"{}"
    pre.format(searchstring)
    pd.read_csv(pre.format(searchstring)) # here I encountered the file not found
```

Because of the quota limit, I usually have to save a lot of subset files and concatenate them.
Any advise would be highly helpful and appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: It's strange that your error message says that `b'C:\\....\\filename_1206_29.csv'` does not exist, which is a bytes object, and not a string. Why is there a bytes object? Also, does the error occur only with the last file, `_29.csv`? Then try to limit your loop to 28, just for debugging.

Comment: did you check if this file really exists ? maybe it doesn't exists or it has little different name. You could also use `os.listdir(folder)` to see what filenames can see Python.

Comment: to add `0` in filename you don't need `if/else` but string formating `'{:02}'` - `"Scopus_FrOid_1206_{:02}.csv".format(i)` - see more on [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: btw: `i` is a number, not string, you don't have to use `int(i)`. If you really would need to use `if/else` tnen you can do `if i<10: i = '0' + str(i)`. But shorter will be use `{:02}` directly in filename

Comment: The files are all already here as they had been created by a API and now I just wanted to concatenate all of them in one file and I thought this would be the way for me to save some typing from 1 to 28. I succeeded having all the files with pre='r"{}"' and used pre.format() I got all the file names but when I added pd.read_csv() in front it did not work and got an error said the file not found..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, and I also referred to the solution of other question as here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534745/9340081

The code I used to solve my case is as below:

```
content=[]
for i in range(0,28):
    i+=1
    if len(str(int(i)))==1:
        i='0'+str(int(i))
    else:
        i=str(int(i))
    filename="""FileName_1206_{}.csv"""
    search=filename.format(i)
    content.append(pd.read_csv(search))

df=pd.concat(content, ignore_index=True)
df
```