# Filter sub-dataframe in nested for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I'd like to filter a dataframe to get sub-datasets in a nested for-loop, then apply `some_function` to each sub-datasets, pick one row from each sub-dataset based on time duration column called `TimeDiff`, then concatenate all the individual rows into one dataframe.

Here's the code:

```
def tm(df):
    total_t = []
    df['YearMonth'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
    
    for yearmonth in df['YearMonth'].unique():
        for id in df['Id'].unique():

            sub_df = df[(df['YearMonth'] == yearmonth) &(df['Id'] == id)]
            res_df = some_function(sub_df)
            res_df['TimeDiff'] = res_df['EndTime'] - res_df['StartTime'] 
            res_df = res_df.loc[(res_df['TimeDiff']> datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)) & (res_df['TimeDiff']<datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))]
            long_event = res_df.loc[res_df['TimeDiff'] ==res_df['TimeDiff'].max()]
            
            total_t.append(pd.Series(long_event))
            # total_t.append(pd.Series(long_event))
            total_t = pd.concat([total_t])

    return total_t

tm(dfx)
```

`res_df` is a dataframe looks as below:

```
    Id  Date        StartTime               EndTime                 StartVal EndVal TimeDiff
0   89  2012-03-10  2012-03-10 00:00:08.483 2012-03-10 00:00:11.607 41.5     41.0   00:00:03.124000
1   181 2012-03-10  2012-03-10 00:02:49.687 2012-03-10 00:02:52.813 41.5     41.0   00:00:03.126000
```

I want to pick the row with longest `TimeDiff`, and also in the range of `60seconds` to `5minutes` in each sub-dataset to combine them into one dataframe.

However it caught error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

I realised that it may be due to the fact that the dataframe passed as arguments should be of `list` form based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459002/11901732). I tried

```
total_t = pd.concat([total_t])
# Original code :total_t = pd.concat(total_t)
```

which returned:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Expected Output, still in this format but more rows:

```
    Id  Date        StartTime               EndTime                 StartVal EndVal TimeDiff
0   89  2012-03-10  2012-03-10 00:00:08.483 2012-03-10 00:00:11.607 41.5     41.0   00:00:03.124000
1   181 2012-03-10  2012-03-10 00:02:49.687 2012-03-10 00:02:52.813 41.5     41.0   00:00:03.126000
                                            ...
```

---

Update:

Tried:

```
            total_t.append(long_event)
            total_t = pd.Series(total_t)
#             total_t = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([total_t]))
            total_t = pd.concat([total_t])
```

which only returned one row:

```
0     Id   Date       StartTime               EndTime                   StartVal 
EndVal TimeDiff
37    235  2012-03-10 2012-03-10 19:43:32.260 2012-03-10 19:48:06.270   42.0 
41.5   00:04:34.010000
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to return a `pd.DataFrame` containing, for each `YearMonth` and for each `Id`, the maximum `TimeDiff` under 5 minutes. Is that right ?

A few comment on your code first:

- At the first iteration of `total_t.append(pd.Series(long_event))` `total_t` is a list, so you can append inplace as you did.
- The next line: `total_t = pd.concat([total_t])` will transform your list into a Series
- From the second iteration, `total_t.append(pd.Series(long_event))` will be executed, but as `total_t` became a `pd.Series` the append operation is not inplace anymore.

**I would suggest you the following adjustments:**

To get the line corresponding to the maximum TimeDiff, you can use this:

```py
long_event = res_df.loc[res_df['TimeDiff'].idxmax()]
```

Then you can append them quite likeas you already do (no need to convert to a `pd.Series`):

```py
total_t.append(long_event)
```

Finally, I would remove `total_t = pd.concat([total_t])` by adding just before the return

```py
total_t = pd.DataFrame(total_t)
```

The final code would look like this:

```py
            long_event = res_df.loc[res_df['TimeDiff'].idxmax()]
            total_t.append(long_event)

    total_t = pd.DataFrame(total_t)
    return total_t
```

**Test with sample data**

Creation of fake data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeDiff': ['00:01:13.124000', '00:00:03.124000', '00:12:03.126000', '00:04:54.124000'], 
                   'Other': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['TimeDiff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.TimeDiff)
```

Result

```py
df = df.loc[(df['TimeDiff']> datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)) & (df['TimeDiff']<datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))]
total_t = []
long_event = df.loc[df['TimeDiff'].idxmax()]
total_t.append(long_event)

# after the for loops are completed in your case
total_t = pd.DataFrame(total_t)
total_t
    TimeDiff                    Other
3   0 days 00:04:54.124000000   4
```

The `Other` column is here just to prove that the result is a `DataFrame` and therefore contains all your other columns in the end.

Comment: Hi Hugolmn, thank you for sharing your thoughts on the problem. The focus of the problem lies in the fact that I could not produce a structured table for the output for each subdataset, after applying the same functions. And each sub-dataset contains the data for each month, each unique id. I later realised that I could  apply the same functions and group the entire dataset by month and id, which is more straightforward.