# concatenate dataframe with dataframe from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I want to concatenate a dataframe (`df`) with another dataframe that is stored in a list of dataframes.

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3]
```

What I want is a dataframe like below

```
new_dflist = [df+df1, df+df2, df+df3]
```

```
new_dflist = []
for n in dflist:
    new_dflist.append(pd.concat(df, dflist[n]))
```

but I get the error message
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame`

I also tried with `enumerate` but I get the error message
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dflist = [df1, df2, df3]
new_dflist=[]
for n in dflist:
    new_dflist.append(pd.concat([df, n]))
```

`n` is a dataframe and you are trying to put it in list index

Answer (score 0):

> but I get the error, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame

That is because `n` is a dataframe, not an integer. You seem to think that  for loop gives you the indexes in a list, but it actually gives you the items directly. Just change your code to use the dataframe from the for loop iterator:

```
new_dflist=[]
for new_df in dflist:
    new_dflist.append(pd.concat([df, new_df]))
```

Alternatively, you can do this in a single line with a list comprehension:

```
new_dflist=[pd.concat([df, new_df]) for new_df in dflist]
```

Comment: Thanks! This gave me an error "TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"" but this post helped me solve that problem!! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534676/typeerror-first-argument-must-be-an-iterable-of-pandas-objects-you-passed-an-o)

Comment: @michan2378 Thanks for the information. I updated my answer with a fix for that error. This also leads me to a question...is there a reason you don't concatenate all of the dataframes together into a single dataframe?

Comment: yes, I am making a program where the training data for the model is conditional. In this case, dataframe "df" contains data used to train all model the same, and in addition to that, I want to add conditional data that is in dataframes "df1, df2, df3".